# String casting and Unicode in golang

Tags: string, go, unicode, char, byte

I am reading [Go Essentials](https://www.programming-books.io/essential/go/17-strings):

> String in Go is an immutable sequence of bytes (8-bit byte values)
> This is different than languages like Python, C#, Java or Swift where
> strings are Unicode.

I am playing around with following code:

```
s := "日本語"
b :=[]byte{0xe6, 0x97, 0xa5, 0xe6, 0x9c, 0xac, 0xe8, 0xaa, 0x9e}
fmt.Println(string(b) == s) // true

for i, runeChar := range b {
    fmt.Printf("byte position %d: %#U\n", i, runeChar)
}

//byte position 0: U+00E6 'æ'
//byte position 1: U+0097
//byte position 2: U+00A5 '¥'
//byte position 3: U+00E6 'æ'
//byte position 4: U+009C
//byte position 5: U+00AC '¬'
//byte position 6: U+00E8 'è'
//byte position 7: U+00AA 'ª'
//byte position 8: U+009E

for i, runeChar := range string(b) {
    fmt.Printf("byte position %d: %#U\n", i, runeChar)
}

//byte position 0: U+65E5 '日'
//byte position 3: U+672C '本'
//byte position 6: U+8A9E '語'
```

**Questions:**

1. From where does Golang get Unicode for encoding byte array when custing to string? How does `rune` form? Does Golang compiler get Unicode from text file encoding during compilation?
2. What are advantages and disadvantages of implementing String like a byte array, instead of utf-16 chars array like in Java?

Comment: There is no "casting". Go assumes strings are a utf8 encoded series of bytes.

Comment: Question 1 is very cryptic could you clarify? Question 2: Java got it wrong. UTF-16 is a stupid encoding: It's wasteful for ASCII while still not providing big enough range for all codepoints. UTF-8 is the only sensible encoding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are quoting from a weak, unreliable source: [Go Essentials: Strings](https://www.programming-books.io/essential/go/17-strings). Amongst other things, there is no mention of Unicode codepoints or UTF-8 encoding.

---

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := "日本語"
    fmt.Printf("Glyph:             %q\n", s)
    fmt.Printf("UTF-8:             [% x]\n", []byte(s))
    fmt.Printf("Unicode codepoint: %U\n", []rune(s))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/iaYd80Ocitg

Output:

```
Glyph:             "日本語"
UTF-8:             [e6 97 a5 e6 9c ac e8 aa 9e]
Unicode codepoint: [U+65E5 U+672C U+8A9E]
```

---

References:

[The Go Blog: Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](https://blog.golang.org/strings)

[The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)

[Unicode FAQ: UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 & BOM](https://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html)

[The Unicode Consortium](http://unicode.org/)